# Extracting UID information from a URL and sending email to this user

Tags: uri

As a beginner, I would be grateful if this community could help me out to solve the following problem, by giving me some pointers.
This is the scenario I would like to implement in Drupal (I guess I need to create my own module):

A user (“U1”) enters a URL which looks like this:
www.mywebsite/Foo/UID2
Note that U1 does not need to be registered on my web site ( = anonymous), although he / she may be, to access the page which will be invoked through this URL.

U1 is then automatically redirected to a web form page where he / she will enter text: “Hello my name is Bob…”, an email address: “u1@example.com, a phone number “123 345 67 89”.

An email containing this information will be sent to the user that has UID2 as his / her user ID. U1 will not see U2’s email address.

The information that U1 sent an email to U2 will be kept in a “from-to” table which manages the following information:

UID_from (if it exists) 
U_from First Name
U_from Last name
Text_from
Email_from
Telephone_from
UID_to (note: this UDI always belongs to a registered user)
Date & time

Can someone give me some indications of the various functions invoked? If a ready-made module exists (which I did not find), the better.

I suspect hook_menu will be used; but how to extract UI2 from the URL and send it to a web form, which later is handled by an email module?

Thanks so much,

Peter

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem using Out of the box [Webform](https://drupal.org/project/webform) Module.

> Webform is the module for making surveys in Drupal. After a
>   submission, users may be sent an e-mail "receipt" as well as sending a
>   notification to administrators. Results can be exported into Excel or
>   other spreadsheet applications. Webform also provides some basic
>   statistical review and has and extensive API for expanding its
>   features.

- You can read uid value from URL .. Webform has support for tokens. You need to create a field to collect UID and configure default value.

For Example:
%get[key] - Tokens may be populated from the URL by creating URLs of the form http://example.com/my-form?foo=bar. Using the token %get[foo] would print "bar".

- Your URL should be http://example.com/my-form?uid=value .. You will configure default value as %get[uid]
- Webform has Email support out of the box.
- You can see user submitted results in webform you created.
- It automatically creates schema for you, and it has lot more features...